# More than one MESSAGETABLE resource in the same binary

Tags: winapi, resources, event-log, etw

There is a binary that should have both ETW tracing and a message file compiled in. Both files are compiled with the message compiler tool (mc.exe) and produce [MESSAGETABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381027(v=vs.85).aspx) binaries that should be subsequently compiled into module resources.

mc.exe generates a resource file include that looks like this:

`LANGUAGE 0x9,0x1
1 11 "Module_MSG00001.bin"`

When there are two of these the binary fails to build because of resource the ID duplication. If I change one of the IDs to anything other than 1, the binary builds, but ether logging strings disappear from event viewer or `FormatMessage` API stops decoding error codes from the message table.

Is it possible to have more than one MESSAGETABLE in the same binary so that both event viewer and `FormatMessage` continue to work? I googled quite a bit, but was not able to find the answer so far.

The only way I see how to workaround the problem is to write a tool that merges both message tables into one, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: To workaround the problem I've created [a tiny tool](https://github.com/kirillkovalenko/mtmerge) to merge message table files.

Answer (score 1):

The message table is like the string table. There is only one allowed per language.

The only way to perform this, is to collect all mc file into one large mc file and compile it with `mc.exe` (as you supposed). Saddly `mc.exe` doesn't even take multiple source files. Even when combining the mc files you have to take care that the `LanguageName` block that appears only once.

Writing a program to combine bin files should be possible. 
The data consists of a `MESSAGE_RESOURCE_DATA` structure, which contains one or 
more `MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCKS`, which in turn may consist of one or 
more `MESSAGE_RESOURCE_ENTRY` structures. The structure is similar to 
that of the `STRINGTABLE` resource.

I have an [old link](https://web.archive.org/web/20161111001903/http://www.csn.ul.ie/~caolan/pub/winresdump/winresdump/doc/resfmt.txt) that is broken (I included the link via wayback) that describes the `MESSAGETABLE` format.

**EDIT** The new documentation about the structures can also be found in the MSDN here: [MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648020(v=vs.85).aspx), [MESSAGE_RESOURCE_DATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648021(v=vs.85).aspx), [MESSAGE_RESOURCE_ENTRY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648022(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Yes, the format is documented on MSDN and I have written a merge tool in a couple of hours.